# Как можно получить совпадающие записи в нескольких таблицах

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как можно получить записи из таблиц, совпадающие в минимум двух таблицах? К примеру, все аккаунты у которых одинаковые имена. Таблиц может быть много. В качестве базы данных используется PostgreSQL.

В таблице 1 есть:

```
id   name
--------
11   acc1
12   acc4
13   acc5
14   acc9
15   acc10
```

В таблице 2 есть:

```
id   name
--------
21   acc4
22   acc6
23   acc8
24   acc10
```

В таблице 3 есть:

```
id   name
--------
31   acc1
32   acc7
33   acc9
34   acc8
35   acc10
```

И результат должен быть:

```
id-1  name-1  id-2  name-2  id-3  name-3
----------------------------------------
11    acc1    null  null    31    acc1
12    acc4    21    acc4    null  null
14    acc9    null  null    33    acc9
null  null    23    acc8    34    acc8
15    acc10   24    acc10   35    acc10
```

Comment: почитайте про join

Comment: @lDrakonl я знаю, что join сработает, если будет 2 таблицы, но если будет 3 и больше, то к примеру первая таблица не увидит третью, или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Путаете. В условиях join'a третьей таблицы можно использовать первую. Хотя на самом деле в этом нет необходимости, достаточно будет соединить со второй таблицей, так как с первой соединение будет один к одному

Comment: @lDrakonl Мне все таки кажется, что я ничего не путаю. Если делать join, то он вернет записи, которые совпадают во всех таблицах, а у меня они могут совпадать только в нескольких.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT names.name, table1.id id1, table2.id id2, table3.id id3
FROM ( SELECT name FROM table1
       UNION
       SELECT name from table2
       UNION
       SELECT name from table3
     ) names
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.name = names.name
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.name = names.name
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.name = names.name
```

Если очень хочется получить строго показанную выборку, заменить предложение SELECT на

```
SELECT table1.id "id-1", table1.name "name-1",
       table2.id "id-2", table2.name "name-2",
       table3.id "id-3", table3.name "name-3"
```

> можно ли как-то выводить только те варианты, у которых минимум в двух таблицах есть совпадение, а не все варианты?

```
WHERE (table1.name IS NOT NULL) + (table2.name IS NOT NULL) + (table3.name IS NOT NULL) > 1
```

Comment: Все получается сгруппировано по имени, но можно ли как-то выводить только те варианты, у которых минимум в двух таблицах есть совпадение, а не все варианты?

Comment: как вариант сделать `union all` и  `group by name having count(name) > 1`